# Self hosted web service within winrt application?

Tags: .net, windows-runtime

The native winrt pieces have some great functionality.

But, from our experience, it is not possible to publish a winrt application as a COM server.

So if we build a winrt application, and want to package it to call it from a C#/.NET application, what are our options?

(The calling code will be in IIS/ASP.NET... we can call out to web service, to zeromq endpoint... maybe even out of process COM... or .NET remoting... but what can we put in the winrt application to make it call-able?)

Comment: Why are you trying to build this as a WinRT application? Does it have UI? (Your other question you recently posted asked about "services", so it's not clear what type of app you're building).

Comment: @WiredPrairie  There is some good functionality in winrt libs that is not available elsewhere in win/.net (e.g. Windows.Data and Windows.Services and others). So, we wanted to use some of those in our .NET win app.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj856306.aspx might help.

Comment: @WiredPrairie Thanks. Turns out winrt is a non starter. Cannot use it for background task/service. Bummer!

Answer (score 1):

With Windows 10 you have a new option that might be of interest for you:

You can create an **App Service**. This is basically an app that can be started by another app and executes some predefined function on request without appearing on the UI. It doesn't always run, it only starts to run when another app calls it.
Under the hood an app service is an app implementing a background task that is triggered by an appservicetrigger. Find more info on app services here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt187314.aspx

These App Services can also be called by desktop applications (e.g. WPF applications). Here's a sample for an app service called by a WPF app: https://aruntalkstech.wordpress.com/2015/07/20/calling-an-app-service-from-a-wpfwinforms-win32-app/

Comment: Interesting! The app service is a pure winrt app? Will it run on win2012R2?

Comment: Hi! It's a pure Windows Universal Platform App: It will only run on Windows 10.

Comment: If it is win-10 only, that is not useful. We require a platform that can run on win10 and win2012-R2.